# Questions about a subgroup of a quotient group

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Suppose I have an abelian group $G$ and its subgroups $H$ and $T$. 
Let me mod out the group by $T$. Then I am sure that the subgroup $\{ \bar{h} : h \in H \}$ of $G/T$ is isomorphic to the group $H/(H\cap T)$. Here $\bar{h}$ is $h$ mod $T$. I was wondering if someone could point out how I can prove this fact?
Thank you very much.

Comment: Consider the homomorphism $H \rightarrow (H+T)/T,~h \mapsto h+T$ and use the first isomorphism theorem.

Comment: @SebastianSchoennenbeck So the first isomorphism theorem tells me that $(H+T)/T$ is isomoprhic to $H/(H \cap T)$ but how is this helpful here...?

Comment: I am not sure I am following, wasn't that exactly your question? $H+T$ is not a subgroup of of $G/T$, but it gives rise to the subgroup $(H+T)/T$ of $G/T$ and this subgroup (by the above argument) is isomorphic to $H/(H \cap T)$.

Comment: @SebastianSchoennenbeck Sorry, I think my question was not clear. Let me fix this...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Show that the map $ h \to \bar h  $ is a homomorphism $H\to G/T$ with kernel $=H\cap T$

Apply general result (Law of Homomorphisms?) $\frac {\mathrm {Dom} f}{\mathrm {Ker} f} \cong \mathrm {Image} f$

Comment: You wouldn't happen to have written some papers on one-relator groups in the 70s, would you?...

Comment: user1729 yes i did

Comment: Brilliant! I am delighted to meet you (however oddly, on the internet). I enjoy thinking about one-relator groups, so have read a few of your papers.

Comment: @user1729 Thank you. As I recall there are only a few. Of course if you have any questions about them you can ask here. If you want to just chat, I guess we could create a chat room.